# Error de instalación usuario a grupo Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

hace 1 semana compre un notebook y he estado intentando instalar Oracle 12c con el windows que viene de fabrica y llego a este paso siempre que me imposibilita seguir con la instalación y ya no se me ocurre que podría ser, ya que cuando instale SQL Server no tuve problemas al instalarlo.

Si alguien sabe como pueda solucionarlo se lo agradeceria de ante mano ya que sin esto no puedo trabajar en casa para realizar un trabajo para la universidad [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]en donde es necesario que la BD sea Oracle.

Comment: Hola, haz hecho los pasos de instalacion? podrias ver estos pasos https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html

Comment: Segui los pasos pero me arrojo el mismo problema los volvi a descargar version1  y 2 y nada, recuerdo eso si que la primera vez antes de formatear mi pc si se pudo instalar hasta que elimine sin querer todos los path esa vez y por eso lo formatie pero ahora ni idea cual sería el problema, el unico programa que tengo problemas al instalar.

Comment: hola, podrias tambien ejecutar el programa como administrador, clic derecho ejecutar como administrador, asi podria solucionarse creo :D

Answer (score 1):

Yo tuve el mismo problema con oracle 19c. Los solucione asi. Primero desinstala el oracle 12c. Luego le cambias el nombre de tu Pc. Por ejemplos, si tu pc se llama pchogar-01, cambialo por pchogar01 o el nombre que quieras. Volvé a instalar el oracle y listo.

Answer (score 0):

Al final no se que paso, hize sus consejos de ejecutar administrador, y segui los pasos de instalación y nada por lo que opte por formatear el notebook ya que si no avanzaba no iba a poder continuar con mis tareas.

Como conclusión ahora que me pongo a pensar no se si habrá sido un error de puerto o que SQL Server ocupo algo que Oracle ocupaba nose quede perplejo.